# Who and when creates Boundary stereotyped objects

Tags: java, model-view-controller, uml, hexagonal-architecture

In the Entity-Control-Boundary pattern, when is the boundary classes created and initiated, and by which stereotyped class?

This question could also be equivalent to; In the hexagonal-architecture, Whom is responsible for creating Primary Adapters?

Thank you
Mike Brown

Comment: The "ecb" tag on SO has nothing to do with the "ECB" the question is referring to.  You may want to change it to "mvc" or "uml" or "uml-modeling" and perhaps include a language tag like "java".  The question as-is still doesn't seem right for SO.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina thank you, Are these edits suitable?